# Flash and "206 partial conent" http status code

Tags: html, flash, h.264, jwplayer

I use JWPlayer to play videos from the server. Videos are encoded using h.264 codec. If i open them in browser with h.264 support - video plays nicely and i can seek it, because server returns 206 header browser understands that its partial content. But if i try to play same video on Opera, for example, flash player is being used and it receives 200 OK! 2 problems here:

1. *I can't seek the video, until part of it is downloaded*
2. *If the video is not "properly" encoded player can't even start playing it, until file is fully downloaded.*

Is there something wrong with flash properly asking/understanding http headers?(i've never worked with flash before, so maybe my question is a bit silly and i just don't know flash's limitations)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to have pseudo streaming enabled, for Flash - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash, if you can provide a link though, I will take a look at exactly what is going on here, I am more or less guessing about this one. HTML5 does not require a pseudo streaming module to be installed on the server side, though. In Flash, the default is progressive download, so you can only seek to downloaded parts, and in html5, this is not the case.

2) Yes, that is because of encoding. If your MP4 files cannot be seeked before they are completely downloaded, you will have to fix the MOOV atom (it contains the seeking information) located at the end of your video. Use this little application to parse your videos and add the necessary cue points - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Also, encoding via HandBrake - http://handbrake.fr/, can fix this as well, so the above tool wouldn't be necessary. You can encode using HandBrake, and enable "web optimized", which does the same this as the Index Swapper Tool. HandBrake also has command line encoding options as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the links and information provided! Will try it asap!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps! :-)